# div aumentademasiado de altura al agregar boton

Tags: html, css, css3

Puse un botón en un `div` pero al agregarlo el `div` aumenta mucho de altura y queda pegado al `footer`, además el botón se sale del `div`, no sé que puede ser.

```css
.caja {
  height: auto;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 630px;
}

.boton {
  background: #ff4000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-style: normal;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='caja'>--CONTENIDO</div>
<a href="javascript:cargar();" class="boton">MÁS</a>
```

Comment: brindar más detalles por favor para ayudarte, no me queda claro el inconveniente que presentas, saludos.

Comment: El botón no lo has puesto en el div sino fuera del div. Siendo el botón `position: absolute;` y `bottom: 0px; `se va abajo.  Si lo querías en el centro dale también `top:0; height:1em;`o lo que quieras y `margin:auto` en lugar de `margin: 0 auto; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta de esta manera:

```css
.caja {
 height: auto;
 background: #fff;
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 bottom: 630px;
}

.boton {
 background: #ff4000;
 color: #fff;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
 font-style: normal;
 width: 20%;
 margin: auto;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
            <div class='caja'>
              --CONTENIDO
              <button class="boton">
                <a href="javascript:cargar();"></a>MÁS
              </button>
            </div>
  </body>
    </html>
```